# A bounded set is contained in an open ball

Tags: metric-spaces

Given metric space $ (X, d) $ .

> Statement : A set $ E \subset X $ is bounded iff $ \exists $ $ x \in E $ and $ r \in R^{+} $ such that $ E \subset B_{r}(x,d) $.

In the above statement, the set  $ B_{r}(x,d) $ is an open ball.

Is $ B_{r}(x,d) = \{y \in X | d(x, y) < r \}  $ or $ B_{r}(x,d) = \{ y \in E | d(x, y) < r \}  $ , in context of the above statement ?

Comment: the first one, of course $E$ is then also contained in the second set.

Comment: The assertion $E\in B_r(x,d)$ makes no sense. It should be $E\subset B_r(x,d)$.

Comment: That was a typo, I have edited it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct characterization of a bounded set in a metric space $(X,d)$ is:

$E \subset X$ is bounded iff there exists an $r>0$ and a point $x \in E$ (can be also just $x \in X$) such that $E \subset B_r(x) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y)<r \}$. I.e. $E$ must be contained in **some** open ball.